# How to use audio files loading in each slide in fullpage.js?

Tags: audio, slideshow, fullpage.js

I want to build a slideshow where each slide has a sound file associated to it, so whenever scroll or click to the next slide, the sound will play. I know how to use afterRender: to play video, but i´m not really sure how should i proceed with sound files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can load all of them on page load, on the HTML markup, so there will be no delay when accessing to the slide to load the audio file.

Load all of them but don't play them. And only play them when accessing to the slides by using [`afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex).

About how to play the audio, you should figure that by yourself or open another question for it.